# SQL Server 2008 R2 log shows backups (I/O suspend, resume) several times an hour

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am troubleshooting a server issue that may or may not be related...
On my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance running on Windows Sever 2008 R2 (VMWare), the logs show:
Each database is backed up every 6 to 9 minutes with the following sequence of log entries:

Date        5/19/2014 3:29:24 AM - I/O is frozen on database master. No user action is required. However, if I/O is not resumed promptly, you could cancel the backup.

Date        5/19/2014 3:29:45 AM - I/O was resumed on database master. No user action is required.

Date        5/19/2014 3:30:53 AM - Database backed up. Database: master, creation date(time): 2014/05/18(16:13:28), pages dumped: 425, first LSN: 1198:80:1, last LSN: 1198:96:1, number of dump devices: 1, device information: (FILE=1, TYPE=VIRTUAL_DEVICE: {'{41FEC1EB-EEB7-4363-A88E-CECBE3B0F5FA}22'}). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

This sequence of 3 entries is repeated for each database every 6 to 9 minutes. This behavior seems to have stopped after a server reboot, but I am still looking for clues as to what went wrong in the first place (still dealing with extreme intermittent server slowness). Does anyone have any ideas as to what would cause the above to happen?

Comment: `I am troubleshooting a server issue that may or may not be related` Related to what? Have you checked for maintenance plans or jobs that may be backing up the databases or logs?

Comment: @joeqwerty Related to my larger issue of extreme slowness on the server. There are no jobs or maintenance plans that would be backing up the databases more than once per day.

Comment: @jlnorsworthy Those appear to just be VSS backups completing OK... To troubleshoot performance you should start from Activity Monitor, see what queries wait and what the wait resource is.